Merge old and new versions of the same MariaDB database
I did a server migration and when I ported the databases from the old server to the new one there was some data corruption. In example IPv6 binary data looks exactly the same however entries from the old server are often returned as empty. The records created on the new server are fine. There has been no changes to the database structure in any way.
How do I take the original exports from the old server and import only the new records from the new server's databases?

If you're willing to do an extra query per table you can completely drop the IGNORE syntax and get results with zero warnings via SHOW WARNINGS;:
INSERT INTO $database1.$table 
SELECT * FROM $database2.$table 
WHERE $database2.$table.$id>(SELECT MAX($id) FROM $database1.$table)

